# encoding problems postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I am trying to do a search for Cyrillic names(rus name), but the function returns an empty list.

doctrine config

```
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'dbname' => 'app',
            'user' => 'app',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'host' => 'db',
            'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
        ]
    ]
```

Search function:

```php
    $qb->andWhere('LOWER(user.name) LIKE :searchTerm')
                ->setParameter('searchTerm', strtolower('%' . $query['name'] . '%'));
```

What i tried:

```
    'charset' => 'SQL_ASCII' and 'charset' => 'utf8'
```